# Extracting responses from Microsoft DNS Server Analytical logs

Tags: windows, logging, dns-server, parsing

Is it possible to extract the DNS responses from Microsoft DNS Server Analytical logs (Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server/Analytical)? The logs contain a field called "PacketData" in the EventData section of the event, but so far I have unable to extract anything useful from the PacketData field.

Comment: Why do you want to track *responses*? You could just send a request to see the same answer. As of today, there is no way to extract given responses (aka "how many time google.com has been requested and by whom").

Comment: @bjoster: Basically for passive DNS purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places to find Windows DNS server logs - first, as you mentioned is via the DNS debug log file. There is also data available via Windows ETW Providers (**Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server-Service**, **Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer**). I've used something like Microsoft Message Analyzer to do an event trace session, also a log collector NXLog (note: am involved in that project) to collect event trace data from the ETW Provider and write these out to JSON.

I know for sure that the **PacketData** field is found when you do an ETW trace of the **Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer** ETW Provider. See below for an excerpt using NXLog [im_etw](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide-full#im_etw) module with the JSON output.

```
{
    "EventTime": "2017-03-10 09:51:03",
    "Provider": "Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer",
    "TCP": "0",
    "InterfaceIP": "10.2.0.162",
    "Source": "10.2.0.198",
    "RD": "1",
    "QNAME": "nickelfreesolutions.com.",
    "QTYPE": "1",
    "XID": "11675",
    "Port": "22416",
    "Flags": "256",
    "BufferSize": "41",
    "PacketData":
"0x2D9B01000001000000000000136E69636B656C66726565736F6C7574696F6E7303636F6D0000010001",
    "EventReceivedTime": "2017-03-10 09:51:04",
    "SourceModuleName": "etw_in",
    "SourceModuleType": "im_etw"
}
```

Comment: We are using exactly the same setup in this case (NXLog + JSON), and I know that the PacketData field is there. My question rather is that how exactly should I decode the data and whether it should contain the response or not?

Comment: @treiman I would also suggest adding the topic on the community forum https://nxlog.co/community-forum - good luck!